# Can the coefficients of a linear combination be functions of the variables?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear combination over $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ with coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, if $a_i = f(v_i) \in \mathbb{R}$ for some function $f$, would $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ still be a linear combination?

Comment: The vector $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$ would still be a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. But I think one would not say that the function $(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$ is linear in its arguments.

Comment: Here the $v_i$ are fixed, so whatever $f$ is, $f(v_i)$ are fixed scalars. So, unless you have a different context in mind, yes. Maybe you should edit with explicit context.

Comment: What is your $f$? Do you want $f$ to be in the dual space?